# How initialize weights of a `torch.nn.Transformer` module?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I am using a vanilla transformer architecture from the "Attention Is All You Need" paper for a sequence-to-sequence task. As shown in the following code.
Assuming that I would like to use the `torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform_` initialization method, how would one go about initializing the weights of the `nn.Transformer` ?
Is it necessary to use a custom encoder and decoder class in order for that to happen?

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import math

# helper Module that adds positional encoding to the token embedding to introduce a notion of word order.
import torch.nn as nn
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 emb_size: int,
                 dropout: float,
                 maxlen: int = 20):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()

        den = torch.exp(- torch.arange(0, emb_size, 2)* math.log(10000) / emb_size)
        pos = torch.arange(0, maxlen).reshape(maxlen, 1)
        pos_embedding = torch.zeros((maxlen, emb_size))
        pos_embedding[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(pos * den)
        pos_embedding[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(pos * den)
        pos_embedding = pos_embedding.unsqueeze(-2)

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.register_buffer('pos_embedding', pos_embedding)

    def forward(self, token_embedding: Tensor):
        return self.dropout(token_embedding + self.pos_embedding[:token_embedding.size(0), :])

# helper Module to convert tensor of input indices into corresponding tensor of token embeddings
class TokenEmbedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size: int, emb_size):
        super(TokenEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, emb_size)
        # Initialize weights with He initialization
        self.embedding.weight = nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.embedding.weight)
        self.emb_size = emb_size

    def forward(self, tokens: Tensor):
        return self.embedding(tokens.long()) * math.sqrt(self.emb_size)

# Seq2Seq Network 
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 src_vocab_size: int,
                 tgt_vocab_size: int,
                 num_encoder_layers: int = 1,
                 num_decoder_layers: int = 1,
                 emb_size: int = 300,
                 nhead: int = 3,
                 dim_feedforward: int = 512,
                 dropout: float = 0.1,
                 activation_function='relu'):
        super().__init__()
        self.src_tok_emb = TokenEmbedding(src_vocab_size, emb_size)
        self.tgt_tok_emb = TokenEmbedding(tgt_vocab_size, emb_size)
        self.positional_encoding = PositionalEncoding(
            emb_size, dropout=dropout)
        
        self.transformer = torch.nn.Transformer(d_model=emb_size,
                                       nhead=nhead,
                                       num_encoder_layers=num_encoder_layers,
                                       num_decoder_layers=num_decoder_layers,
                                       dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward,
                                       dropout=dropout,
                                       batch_first=True,
                                       activation=activation_function)
        self.generator = nn.Linear(emb_size, tgt_vocab_size)
    
    def init_weights(self):
      self.generator.weight = nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(self.generator.weight)
      
    def forward(self,
                src: Tensor,
                trg: Tensor,
                src_mask: Tensor,
                tgt_mask: Tensor,
                src_padding_mask: Tensor,
                tgt_padding_mask: Tensor,
                memory_key_padding_mask: Tensor):
        # the .permute() is necessary since the positional-encoder expects tensors to be of shape
        # (seq_len, batch_size, emb_length)
        src_emb = self.positional_encoding(self.src_tok_emb(src).permute(1,0,2)).permute(1,0,2)
        tgt_emb = self.positional_encoding(self.tgt_tok_emb(trg).permute(1,0,2)).permute(1,0,2)
        outs = self.transformer(src_emb, tgt_emb, src_mask, tgt_mask, None, 
                                src_padding_mask, tgt_padding_mask, memory_key_padding_mask)
        return self.generator(outs)

    def encode(self, src: Tensor, src_mask: Tensor):
        return self.transformer.encoder(self.positional_encoding(
                            self.src_tok_emb(src)), src_mask)

    def decode(self, tgt: Tensor, memory: Tensor, tgt_mask: Tensor):
        return self.transformer.decoder(self.positional_encoding(
                          self.tgt_tok_emb(tgt)), memory,
                          tgt_mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

The torch.nn.Transformer consists of multiple parts and weights. To initialize the transformer, you need to initialize each part separately. The following code demonstrates how to initialize the all weights of the transformer using torch.nn.init.kaiming_uniform:

```
for name, param in former.named_parameters():
    if 'weight' in name and param.data.dim() == 2:
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(param)
```

if you want initialize only one parts weights you can follow:

```
state_dict = transformer.state_dict()
state_dict['encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_weight'] = nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(state_dict['encoder.layers.0.self_attn.in_proj_weight'])
```

you can find all layers name by

```
state_dict.key()
```